# Python Selenium multiple threads wont work

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium

I worked with selenium in python. I wanted to make the program multithreaded (4-10 threads) but it wont work. I don't know why.

When I start:
Output:
Thread started!

What should happen:
Output:
Thread started!
Thread started!
Thread started!
Thread started!
Thread started!
...

Here is what I tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import string
import random
import time
from threading import Thread


def bot():
    while True:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])  # Disables logging
        options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
        options.add_argument("--incognito")
        options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery");
        options.add_argument("--headless") # Turns Chrome into headless browser
        options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get("https://example.com/")
        driver.close()


def main():
    for _ in range(10):
        print("Thread started!")
        worker = Thread(target=bot())
        worker.setDaemon(True)
        worker.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three problems. First, you said:

```
worker = Thread(target=bot())
```

It should be:

```
worker = Thread(target=bot)
```

The second problem is the following line:

```
worker.setDaemon(True)
```

Can you say why you did this? A daemon thread is one that will automatically terminate as soon as all the non-daemon threads terminate. You have one non-daemon thread, namely the main thread that is launching all these daemon threads in function `main()`. As soon as `main` returns, which is *immediately* after starting all these dameon threads, it terminates! And thus all the daemon threads terminate with it. This is what you need:

```
def main():
    threads = [Thread(target=bot) for _ in range(10)]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join() # wait for this thread to terminate
```

The third problem is in function `bot`:

```
driver.close()
```

should be:

```
driver.quit()
```

To not only close the window but to also terminate the process and allow the thread to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to remove the `while True` in your `bot()` function? Threading means the main program executes your secondary function multiple times.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer.
Yes but I need it in loop.
Is there any way to get this work?

Comment: And yes I tried it without loop also. But it's waiting until the process is finished. After process is finished the next thread gets started. I need to start all 10 threads at the same time.

Comment: You have to define a certain number of loops or a break condition to make it work or else the first thread won't end. If you want to launch them in parallel, you can try multiprocessing in Python instead.https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: @sboomi _...If you want to launch them in parallel, you can try multiprocessing..._ great observation.